# How can I calculate power in an ANOVA when I only know how many levels and IVs I have, before I have any data?

Tags: anova, statistical-power

I have two design models:

IV1: Level 1: 15

IV1: Level 2: 15

IV2: Level 1: 15

IV2: Level 2: 15

In my second trial, IV3 is Fixed and IV4 is Random. So I have (DF:1x1x2=2):

IV3: Level 1: 15

IV3: Level 2: 15

IV4: Level 1: 10

IV4: Level 2: 10

IV4: Level 3: 10

How do I calculate the power in each of these before I have any data?

Comment: You will need an estimate for your effect size to calculate power.

Comment: Hi Gregg, thank you. How do I figure out an estimate for my effect size?

Comment: This requires consulting the literature for past research to come up with a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Thank you, I'm consulting my notes and if I assume a large effect size, that would be 0.8, right?

Comment: Sophie, your effect size is **the smallest difference in means that you, the researcher, would find relevant**.